# How to revoke cookies tracking permission on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, permission, cookies

Today, when I logged in my Outlook account, a pop up dialog appeared asking me whether I allow “microsoftonline.com” to use cookies and website data while browsing “microsoft.com”. It does not allow me to login if I choose Don’t Allow, but after I press Allow, I cannot find a way to revoke the permission.

[image]

Does anyone know if there is such a setting to revoke the permission? I’m on iOS 14.